# how to upload excel to database using springboot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to springboot, need help in uploading the excel data to the oracle database table.
i have set up the sprinboot environment and database is connected and able to get the table data.

Answer (score 0):

Upload it as `multi-part` file in API,

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload-excel")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
public bool uploadMutipleDocuments(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile file) {
    return uploadService.uploadFile(file);
}
```

In your, `service` class invoke the `repository` to `save` the file in `database`.

Comment: i wrote code, with it able to add table but unable to add the content

Comment: Controller class: 
public class DgDataController {
 
 @Autowired
 private DgDataService ds;
 
 @RequestMapping("/upload-excel")
 public void setDataInDB() {
  System.out.println("set Data in DB");
  ds.saveDgData();
   
 }

Comment: Service class:
public class DgDataService {
 @Autowired DgDataRepo dgre;
 String line="";
 public void saveDgData() {
  try {
   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/main/resources/DG.xlsx"));
   while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
    System.out.println("Buffered Reader before split");
    String [] data=line.split(",");
    DgDataTable d=new DgDataTable();
    d.setDgnumber(data[0]);
    d.setDqnumber(data[1]);
    d.setStatus(data[2]);
    dgre.save(d);
   }
   
  } catch (IOException e) {
   
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: Model class with fields, getter n setter, to String, constuctor.
And Repo with below code 
public interface DgDataRepo extends JpaRepository<DgDataTable, Long> {

}

Comment: how do i modify it ?